# StoryBook React hook

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, storybook

So I used useLocation hook in my code and I am new to storybook I couldn't figure out a way to initialize that hook in my code:

```
let location = useLocation();

const parsedLocation = new URLSearchParams(location.search)
const query = parsedLocation.get('query')
const {articles, status} = useSearch(query, 50)
```

**IN STORYBOOK**

```
const Template = (args) => <Page {...args} />;

export const Primary = Template.bind({});
 Primary.args = {
   location: useLocation()
};
```

// Its showing me error that Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `useLocation();` to container component where you collect all data and handle events. Pass `query` as a props to children component.

In Storybook use mocked data to build this component. Storybook is more for developing UI part of components. To test using `useLocation()` hook you can use unit tests.

In case you need to mock some URL location for your component, consider using MemoryRouter https://reactrouter.com/web/api/MemoryRouter